# Can't run Puma after deploying with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, puma

After deploying my Rails 5 (Ruby 2.3.7) application with Capistrano, I try run on my 'current' folder (with no luck) this command:

```
bundle exec puma -e production -b unix:/home/deploy/my_app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"
```

I get the following error (note that I've set Ruby version to 2.3.7 in the Gemfile, but the error mentions 2.3.0)

```
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma)
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - connect(2) for /home/deploy/my_app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
  /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:370:in `initialize'
  /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:370:in `new'
  /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:370:in `add_unix_listener'
  /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:141:in `block in parse'
  /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `each'
  /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `parse'
  /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:151:in `load_and_bind'
  /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/single.rb:96:in `run'
  /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:184:in `run'
  /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:78:in `run'
  /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
  /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

This is on a EC2 instance with Ubuntu 18.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the tutorial im following
http://www.dsolc.com/blogs/8-deploying-rails-app-to-ec2-instance-with-capistrano-using-nginx-and-puma

Comment: Check that `/home/deploy/my_app/shared/tmp/sockets/` dir exists.

Comment: That was it. I can't belive it. Thank you so much arieljuod!

Comment: try this command `bundle exec puma -C /home/deploy/my_app/shared/puma.rb --daemon`

Comment: before that check any running port of puma by `ps aux | grep puma` and kill those ports